# Redirect to Error Page Fail on Application Error in Global.asax (MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, global-asax

I am having a hard time trying to redirect to my error handling controller when an application error is encountered in Global.asax.

Here is my RouteCollection

```
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        "DefaultError",
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { controller = "HndlError", action = "AllErrors", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

And My `Global.asax` `Application_Error` has this

```
                this.Context.Response.Clear();
                this.Context.ClearError();
                //this.Response.Redirect("~/HndlError/AllErrors") // This one Works !!!


                this.Response.RedirectToRoute( new { controller = "HndlError",
 action = "AllErrors", id = ErrorMessage }); // This does not Work

                this.Response.End();
```

My Controller Action does get hit while using `Response.Redirect` but returns a blank page with `RedirectToRoute` . Did some more searching and then came across this GEM !

[Beware of ResponseRedirectToRoute in MVC 3](http://blog.slaks.net/2011/11/beware-of-responseredirecttoroute-in.html)

Does that mean it will not work in MVC3 or am i missing something ? Please Help.

thanks

Comment: Remove `this.Response.End();` from end of `Application_Error`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;
    ctx.Response.Clear();
    RequestContext rc =((MvcHandler)ctx.CurrentHandler).RequestContext;
    rc.RouteData.Values["action"] = "AllErrors";

    rc.RouteData.Values["controller"] = "HndlError";
    rc.RouteData.Values["id"] = ErrorMessage ;

    IControllerFactory factory = ControllerBuilder.Current.GetControllerFactory();
    IController controller = factory.CreateController(rc, "HndlError");
    controller.Execute(rc);
    ctx.Server.ClearError();
}
```